# Jump back to the position I started a search

Tags: search, mark, jump

I have a small question: let's suppose I'm at the beginning of line 10 and I search a term with the command `/term_to_search` and then I press `<Enter>` to start navigating search results with `n` or `N`. Then I want to go back to the location I were before starting the search (the beginning of line 10). How can I do? I know that the commands `CTRL+O` and `CTRL+I` jump back and forth the list of jumps, but how can I do it in just one keypress? Do I need to define a new special mark to do that (if so, how)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I do this by first creating a mark - for example, create a mark named "a" with `ma` in command mode – then search or move around the file however you want. Then go back to your mark with `'a`.

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of off the top of my head:

1. `:[v]split`, then search in only one window
2. `:nnoremap / mz/`; then `` `z `` should take you back. Only works for one search at a time (i.e. new searches overwrite the mark)

Answer (score 2):

> let's suppose I'm at the beginning of line 10

Then the easiest way back is `10G` or `:10`. It's not that useless if you have line numbers on and your memory is not bad either.

Also, sometimes the command `g;` (go back one position in *the change list*) proves to be be useful.

Answer (score 0):

*If, contrary to my initial thinking, OP just wants a way to do what they describe manually (and the voting so far suggests that's most people are reading it that way) then this is overkill. But if one wants a transparent, automated method that allows return to search start any time w/o having to think about it ahead of time....this should help...*

If we want to get a little fancier (though still down and dirty) we can create an autocommand and a mapping like so...

```
augroup searchorigin
  autocmd!
  au CmdLineLeave * let b:cmdtype = expand('<afile>') | if (b:cmdtype == '/' || b:cmdtype == '?') | let b:searchorigin = getpos(".") | endif
augroup END

nnoremap <leader>/ :exec 'call setpos(".", b:searchorigin)'<CR>
```

The autocommand will record the starting point of your current search in a buffer-local variable, allowing this to work simultaneously on different searches occurring in different buffers. The mapping will move the cursor back to that point using that variable.

So just start a search as you always do and then hit `\/` and you'll be back to the start point. (Replace `<leader>/` in the mapping with whatever free key(s) you desire.)

Comment: Registers != marks, and marks are buffer local for the lowercase.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Umm. Okay. Who said otherwise?

Comment: read your last points as counterarguments to the mark answer. I guess you know what they say when you assume 

Comment: My first (ill advised) inclination was to store `getpos()` result in a register...that's the origin of that bullet point (which is kind of superfluous in retrospect).